# JQuery: How to detect mobile width and change my css to it's with using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to detect mobile width and change my css to it's current window width using jquery?

For Example

```
.page {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 40px 0;
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 720px;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 360px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and then I have this function but I am not sure if it's really working.

```
function responsiveFn() {
    width = $(window).width();
    document.getElementById('widthID').innerHTML = width;
    jQuery('.page').css({
        max-width: width
    });
}
```

Thanks for the answer in advance! :)

Comment: That should work fine except `max-width` inside `css` should be covered in **' '** !! what you are getting as now?

Comment: Mate, it's still not adjusting. I am using this for mobile. Actually I have Div (wrapper) inside div (index):

`<div id="wrap"> <div data-role="page" id="index" class="page">`

#wrap {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 1200%;
        }

Because it's a horizontal scrolling, I divided my pages in this 1200%.

Comment: When you are calling the above function?

Comment: Inside the head tags.

Comment: You need to trigger that function!

Comment: `window.onresize = responsiveFn;` but still not adjusting. I try to change the max-width directly and it's working. That's why I am trying to just change the max-width using jquery. Then when it detects the right width, it will adjust just perfectly.

Comment: did you cover `max-width` with `'max-width'`

Comment: Can you create a demo **[here](https://jsfiddle.net)**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69r1a2g0/ okay mate, I think I should just need to change my wrap to 900% then my .page to 11.1%

Comment: Can you please tell what element is `widthID`? and have you included `jquery` file?

Comment: `Width: <span id="widthID"></span>` I just use that for this. So I can see if it is changing but it's not. I think I should just change the way I code this horizontal web. Any suggestion mate on how will I make my web horizontal and responsive at the same time?

Comment: `jquery` file included in your page?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.min.js"></script>

Comment: you have to be more precised!! Just post maximum code including html if possible. Edit your question and do the same please!

Comment: I done it right but in different way. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using Javascript/jQuery, check the below points.

Suggestions:

1. Use `width` in percentages so, when resized it'll auto adjust
2. Use `media queries` for resolution specific styles
3. When setting properties from Javascript, use quotes around property name or use camelcase. Ex. maxWidth, or 'max-width'

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .page {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

3. Create separate CSS file for various resolutions and load them for such resolutions

Example:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 600px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

**Update**

If you still want to use Javascript, call your function on window resize event.

```
window.onresize = responsiveFn;
```

Use `max-width` in quotes

```
jQuery('.page').css('max-width', width);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but tired of doing this one. I got this separated css for mobile.

Comment: @Ayuk Kindly check the updated answer, especially the bottom part

Answer (score 0):

Please use media query for all the elements as per your requirement example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:580px) {
    .btn-default {
        float: none;
        max-width: 100%;}
    .textcenter {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

As button and textcenter class will be changed with the mentioned property

Thanks